# Excel insert " : " into general number from right

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have these numbers:

```
930
1345
```

Which are actually time-of-day values:

```
9:30
13:45
```

How do I insert the ":" into these numbers, given that the hour is not always 2 digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
=TEXT(A1,"#0\:00")
```

or

```
=TEXT(A1,"00\:00")
```

And if you want them converted into times that Excel can use, merely precede the formula with a double unary

```
=--TEXT(A1,"#0\:00")
```

and format the cell as time (eg:  `hh:mm`

Comment: The `TEXT` function will accept a range of cells for the `Value` argument.  I haven't checked it with an array constant but you can surely do that.  Why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

If your number is in cell A1, then this formula will split the number and insert the colon.

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&":"&RIGHT(A1,2)
```

It works for 1 or 2 digit hours.